# Access video on secured FTP Site for streaming

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, streaming, video-streaming

I have a situation where videos reside on an FTP server, and I need to stream them through my Website Project.

Using a very crude method of including the FTP username and password in the URL, I can just drop the formed URL in as a link in the HTML video player.

```
http(s)://username:password@server
```

I am a bit stuck on how to proceed with consuming the video from this remote secured FTP site. There is no web server running to "serve" the videos over http. It is a dedicated FTP server.

Initially, I have played around with making a physical FTP connection from code, but the streaming seemed to be a problem using this method. I just temporarily used the URL authentication method, and it is time to revisit.

Unfortunately, I do not have the original code where I attempted to make the FTP connection through code.

I need to re-visit this, and would like some input before I proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video streaming is quite a specialist area, especially if you want to use techniques like Adaptive Bit Rate streaming (ABR - see note below) to give your users the best possible user experience.

Given this I think the best approach might be for your to FTP the videos to a streaming server where they can be prepared and made available for streaming properly.

There are open source and commercial streaming servers available, some cloud SaaS based, which means you don't have to invent and develop all this yourself. Some examples are:

- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org  (opensource)
- https://www.wowza.com (commercial with free trial)

Note: ABR - this essential means you have multiple versions of your video available on the server. Each is a different bit rate, and all are broken into (for example) 10 second chunks. The client requests the next chunk of the video from whatever is the most appropriate bit rate for the current network conditions. Many clients will also request a low bit rate to start the video to ensure a quick start and then 'step up' through the bit rates to the most appropriate one. You can see this when you start a new video on sites like Netflix etc.

Comment: Hi Mick. Thanks for the answer. I have developed a complete streaming solution before, offering streams in multiple video formats etc similar to what you are suggesting. The issue with this project is that the files are secured on this FTP server for a reason. It is proprietary videos that my client will be selling to its customers for online viewing only. It is also on this FTP server because they are easy to upload and maintain a large number of files through FTP.  Thanks for your input tho, and I will possibly have to suggest a methodology change if nothing else comes up.

Comment: I guess the more usual solution to this, which would maintain all the streaming server functionality advantages, is to use DRM to protect the files. Wowza definitely has DRM support and there are some GStreamer repos on GitHub that claim to support this but I'm not sure how up to date they are. I guess you may not have this flexibility in your case.

Comment: BTW, your customer may not be getting the protection they expect with the FTP approach as the files will have to be unencrypted on most client devices anyway for playback (unless you implement some very complicated secure FTP to DRM interface functionality to keep the video within the device's secure media path!).

Comment: Yes, agreed. There are always caveats, but for now it is "secure enough" on the FTP site. :-) Now, to make that "automagically" work with streaming...